# PHP PDO bindParam for variable/string used for "IN" statement...?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Alright, this is really bothering me. How can I bind a paramater (which has multiple values) for an SQL "IN" statment in PHP's PDO?

Here are the basics...

```
$allow = "'red', 'blue'";

SELECT * FROM colors WHERE type IN (:allow);

$stmt->bindParam(':allow', $allow);
```

This works fine when I plug in $allow by itself, but when trying to bind it and use :allow it fails to work. Does anyone know why this is?

Note: I do have the rest of the PDO properly set with other variables (not strings) working, I just didn't include it because it's unnecessary.

Comment: See [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition). You have to bind each value individually, otherwise the database will try to match on the string "'red', 'blue'", not the two strings "red" and "blue".

Comment: Any here's why people who claim that parameterized queries are the solutions to all of live's problems quietly slink off into the darkness...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What deceze said in the comments is correct.  Here is a way i've done this before.

Basically you create the `IN` part of the sql string by looping the array values and adding in a binded name.

```
$allow = array( 'red', 'blue' );

$sql = sprintf(
    "Select * from colors where type in ( %s )",
    implode(
        ',',
        array_map(
            function($v) {
                static $x=0;
                return ':allow_'.$x++;
            },
            $allow
        )
    )
);
```

This results in `Select * from colors where type in ( :allow_0,:allow_1 )`

Then just loop the `$allow` array and use bindValue to bind each variable.

```
foreach( $allow as $k => $v ){
    $stmnt->bindValue( 'allow_'.$k, $v );
}
```

---

I added this before realizing deceze linked to a question that gave a similar example.  Ill leave this here because it shows how to do it with named binded variables and not ?s

Answer (score -1):

The bind functions will treat the entire list as a string, not multiple discrete values.