# Bind values in raw SQL query, symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have problem with my query. It's working fine in this form:

```
$sql = "SET @i:=0; UPDATE movie m SET m.priority=@i:=@i+1 WHERE m.id IN (". $idsString . ") ORDER BY FIELD(m.id,". $idsString . ")";
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->execute();
```

But imo it's not looking fine.
When I'm trying to use bindParam() (ofc i'm changing parameters to :ids) I don't get error but priorities are not updated. Set parameters in execute don't work because it throw error about array to strig conversion.
I'm doing something wrong or it's other way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you are executing native SQL via the raw connection (PDO). As far as I know binding values with PDO for IN statements is not supported. But you could build the statement with the binding parameters yourself.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808904/1461181

Comment: @DanielO. thanks m8, I'll try it :)

Comment: @DanielO. it's working so rly thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :-)